# display first of class type

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a list of items, each with a class and the class are repeated throughout. I want to only show the first instance of each class. 
Is that possible with just CSS?

```html
<ul>
   <li class="red">red</li>
   <li class="red">red</li>
   <li class="blue">blue</li>
   <li class="blue">blue</li>
   <li class="yellow">yellow</li>
   <li class="red">red</li>
   <li class="yellow">yellow</li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul li {display:none}
ul li .red:first-child, ul li .blue:first-child, ul li .yellow:first-child { display:block}
```

So in the above code, only the 1st, 3rd & 5th list items should show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code and add as many classes as you need.

```
.red,
.blue,
.yellow
{
    display: list-item;
}

.red ~ .red,
.blue ~ .blue,
.yellow ~ .yellow
{
    display: none;
}
```

Check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4V3Ld/) that uses your HTML and only displays the first elements of each class.

This is of course trivial if you have a predefined set of class names. In case your class names are unknown and/or there's an unmanageable amount of them they it would be best to resort to some scripting (using jQuery would help lots)

Comment: You might want to try [`display: list-item;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) instead of `block`, but +1 for the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

Comment: The `~` selector does not exist in CSS 2.1 and below. So this is likely to fail in non-CSS3 browsers.

Comment: @Luc1245: As we can all see OP added CSS3 tag to their question, so this answer reflects this fact. They obviously need CSS3 code and not 2.1

Comment: @Luc1245: The `~` combinator is one of the most widely-supported CSS3 selectors there are in terms of IE (IE7+ and the rest).

Answer (score 0):

In CSS2 you can use:

```
LI .red + .red { display: none; }
LI .blue + .blue { display: none; }
LI .yellow + .yellow { display: none; }
```

where `+` is the [CSS2 adjacent selector](http://www.w3.org/css2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

But I think it is not possible using a single rule for every color at once.

Comment: This will only work, when items with different class names **are not mixed** between each other. To make it work even in that case you'd have to add all class name permutations to make it work.

Answer (score -3):

For any items you want to hide, simply add a id to them.

```
<li class="red">red</li>
<li class="red" id="hide">red</li>
```

CSS:

```
#hide { display:none; }
```

Comment: There can't be multiple items with the same id. I guess you mean `class="hide"` and `.hide`!