# Is there an equivalent to jQuery's :first selector in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following markup:

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div> <!-- :first -->
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div> <!-- :last -->
<div class="c"></div>
```

I'm trying to target the *first* and *last* `<div>` with class `b`.
If I was using jQuery selectors for this, `.b:first` and `.b:last` would do the trick.

However with CSS, that's tricky: the first `<div class="b">` is located after another `<div>` with a different class, and both :first-child and :first-of-type match the first `<div>`, with class `a`.

Is there a selector targeting the first of the items matching the class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [display first of class type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407907/display-first-of-class-type)

Comment: Not *quite* what you're looking for, but the [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) might be of interest?

Comment: @Patrick nope, same as `first-child` and `last-child`, but with an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent CSS selector to jQuery's `:first` or `:last` selector, because those selectors are [filters, and not true simple selectors by the CSS definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983297/difference-between-css-selector-and-jquery-filter/10835694#10835694).

In Selectors 3 there is no `:first-of-class` or similar selector either.

However, you can use overriding rules with the `~` combinator to apply styles to the first child of a certain class:

- [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107)
- [CSS selector to select first element of a given class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615518/css-selector-to-select-first-element-of-a-given-class/3615559#3615559)

But there is currently no way to apply styles to the last child of a certain class using CSS:

- [Is it possible using current browsers to use pseudo-classes to detect first and last of a certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230416/is-it-possible-using-current-browsers-to-use-pseudo-classes-to-detect-first-and/10230466#10230466)

Answer (score 0):

You can always but a wrapper around the divs with the b class also, and target the contents of that using the :first-child and :last-child selectors.

See example here: http://cssdesk.com/fYTHF